# python compare two excel files and delete duplicate data

Tags: python, excel, pandas

i want to delete unsubscribe email in email.xlsx
this is my code

```
import pandas as pd

data_1 = pd.read_excel (r'email.xlsx')

email_data = pd.DataFrame(data_1, columns= ['email'])

email_col = len(email_data)

data_2 = pd.read_excel (r'unsubscribe.xlsx')

unsubscribe_data = pd.DataFrame(data_2, columns= ['unsubscribe'])

unsubscribe_col = len(unsubscribe_data)


for email_num in range(email_col): 

    for unsub_num in range(unsubscribe_col):

            if unsubscribe_data.iloc[unsub_num,0] == email_data.iloc[email_num,0]:

                data_1 = data_1.drop(data_1.index[[email_num]])

                email_data = pd.DataFrame(data_1)    

                print(email_data)
```

when i run this code, i got ' single positional indexer is out-of-bounds'
can you explain the reason why it shows?
THanks.

Comment: Did you want the number of columns or rows here? `email_col = len(email_data)`. This will give you the number of rows not the columns. This can give you the number of columns `email_data.shape[1]`

Answer (score 0):

One thing you can try is to create a new dataframe using the two columns and apply `pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates` on it to remove the duplicates.